# Module help() under python not working

Tags: python, python-3.6

[help function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOSN9.png)
[image]

Hi,
I'm new to python, but have been following a tutorial. I'm trying to use the help() module but I get an error message. i just can't figure it out. Does someone have a clue to my problem or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try running `python` from `cmd.exe` instead.

Comment: I couldn't seem to run it from cmd.exe so I installed the executable installer (instead of the embenddable zip file). It now works. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

help function is not necessary to install, so something is wrong with your python installation.